# Shed electrical

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, shed

I have a 10x16 shop that is 65ft from my panel I want to run power to the shop for a computer a air conditioner which I’ll put on its own breaker since in the winter I will use a heater on that plug. I will also have 5 other plugs and 2 lights. The plugs I’m using are 20A 125V. What kind of wire do I run from my panel in my shop to the other panel.

Comment: "20 v 125 amp"? I don't expect you're running an A/C or heater on low voltage so I assume you mean 125 V, 20 Amp?

Comment: Probably 120V 125A

Comment: What other loads besides the computer, AC, and general lighting will you have in your shed?